# How many signals can be made with the aid of $5$ flags of different colors all arranged in a row?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many signals can be made with the aid of $5$ flags of different colors all arranged in a row?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you have to use all 5 of them?

Answer (score 0):

You have to a arrange 5 different coloured flags in a row. So the first position has 5 options , the next has four options and the next has three options and so on. So total ways is 5!.

Comment: Why are you answering a question the OP has not attempted?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  oh sorry. I thought I would just give a hint when all the 5 flags have to be used and the OP can then use it to form other combinations.

Answer (score 0):

By taking one at a time: $5$

By taking two at a time: $\dbinom{5}{2}2!$

By taking three at a time: $\dbinom{5}{3}3!$

By taking four at a time: $\dbinom{5}{4}4!$

By taking five at a time: $\dbinom{5}{5}5!$

Add all these

Comment: Why are you answering a question the OP has not attempted?

Comment: oh sorry, had not thought about that. I will take care to adhere to the rules henceforth.